# Как из текста с английскими и русскими словами выбрать только русские?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Через selenium парсю c русскоязычной версии википедии прозвища клубов:

```
Канониры (англ. The Gunners)
The Citizens (Горожане)[1]
The Blues (Голубые)[2]
Sky Blues (Небесно-голубые)[1]
Шпоры (англ. The Spurs)
Лилово-белые (англ. The Lilywhites)
Синие (The Blues)[1], Пенсионеры (The Pensioners)[2]
Red Devils (Красные дьяволы)[1]
The Reds (Красные)[2]
```

Но мне надо чтоб были исключительно прозвища на русском языке и если б эти прозвища были в скобках или не в скобках то я б сейчас вопрос не задавал, а так по-разному. И как мне это исправить?

Comment: какие проблемы-то?

Comment: @Эникейщик, так должны быть строки из русских прозвищ, а так как выводится по разному то в скобках, то вначале - не знаю что нужно делать.

Comment: сделайте два значения - в скобках и без скобок, потом выберите из них то, которое на русском

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте применить регулярные выражения

```
import re

txt = """Канониры (англ. The Gunners)
The Citizens (Горожане)[1]
The Blues (Голубые)[2]
Sky Blues (Небесно-голубые)[1]
Шпоры (англ. The Spurs)
Лилово-белые (англ. The Lilywhites)
Синие (The Blues)[1], Пенсионеры (The Pensioners)[2]
Red Devils (Красные дьяволы)[1]
The Reds (Красные)[2]"""

res = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'[а-яА-ЯёЁ \-]+', txt)]
res = list(filter(lambda x: x != '' and x != 'англ', res))
print(res)
```

```
['Канониры', 'Горожане', 'Голубые', 'Небесно-голубые', 'Шпоры', 'Лилово-белые', 'Синие', 'Пенсионеры', 'Красные дьяволы', 'Красные']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

regex = r"(?!\bангл\b)\b[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+(?:[- ][а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*\b"

test_str = """Канониры (англ. The Gunners)
The Citizens (Горожане)[1]
The Blues (Голубые)[2]
Sky Blues (Небесно-голубые)[1]
Шпоры (англ. The Spurs)
Лилово-белые (англ. The Lilywhites)
Синие (The Blues)[1], Пенсионеры (The Pensioners)[2]
Red Devils (Красные дьяволы)[1]
The Reds (Красные)[2]"""

res = re.findall(regex,test_str)

print(res)
```

Вывод:

```txt
['Канониры', 'Горожане', 'Голубые', 'Небесно-голубые', 'Шпоры', 'Лилово-белые', 'Синие', 'Пенсионеры', 'Красные дьяволы', 'Красные']
```

О регулярном выражение:

```regex
(?!\bангл\b)\b[а-яА-ЯЁё]+(?:[- ][а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*\b
```

`(?!\bангл\b)` - негативный просмотр вперед, где слово не является "англ"
`\b` - граница слова
`[а-яА-ЯЁё]+(?:[- ]+[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)*` - одна и более букв кириллицы, после которых возможно появления пробела или тире с обязательным наличием далее одного и более символов кириллицы.

Comment: О, а за что минус? Что не так в ответе?